# Efficient C++ for ARM

Tags: c++, arm

I will give internal training about C++ on ARM, focusing on programming tips and hints, and I searched some webpages like:

- [Embedded C interview Questions for Embedded Systems Engineers](http://www.quickembeddedtips.com/embedded-c-interview-questions-embedded-systems-engineers)
- [Efficient C for ARM](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/efficient-c-for-arm/index.html)

all of above are mainly for C on ARM, in that I am wondering they apply to C++ as well, say struct padding and etc

can you help me on that, T.H.X

Comment: The tips found at Efficient C for ARM apply to most modern CPUs (aside from the "there is no div instruction"). Using char and short to save "space" usually costs a lot more in "time" than is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I didnt look at the first link, the second link Efficient C for ARM is very good, thanks for finding and sharing that, I am going to refer people to that link.

In the same way that the Zen of Assembly language is still as relevant today as when it came out is not because the modern x86 is related to the 8088/86 and the "cycle eaters", but because the thought process and analysis taught doesnt change over time.  The cycle eaters might from language to language or target to target, but how you find them doesnt.  That book was outdated and irrelevant when it came out as far as the tuning for an 8088/86 or so I read somewhere, but I read it then and use what I learned every day since.

Same here the Efficient C for ARM applies well to similar items in C++, but more importantly look at the early slides, before any specific structures or code is shown.  You have to analyze by inspection, and by using a profiler (no different than what Zen of Assembly language says, look at it and time it).  Then the Efficient C for ARM page goes on to inspect some examples, take your C++ code and compile it, then disassemble, and see what is really happening.  The problem with doing that is that you have to realize that there are many tuning knobs on a compiler and compilers are constantly evolving, and different compilers say, gcc, llvm (clang) and visual C/C++ are completely different.  The same C++ source code presented to the different compilers and different versions of the compilers and the same compilers with different optimzation settings is going to produce different results.

When you want to micro-optimize you have to learn a lot of how the compilers work by getting a considerable amount of experience at disassembling and analyzing what the compiler does with your code (FOR EACH TARGET YOU CARE ABOUT).  Only then can you begin to do some real optimization without having to resort to writing assembler.  Despite what folks may tell you you can do this, you can for some situations significantly improve execution performance by simply rearranging structures, functions, lines of code, etc.  Also make code that is more portable to other processors and make code that is generally faster on a number of platforms, not just one.  The nay-sayers are right in that you need to have a good reason for it, sometimes it doesnt change the readability, but often taking it to far makes your code unreadable or unmaintainable or fragile, etc.  Always arrange your structures in a sensible way, larger, aligned variables first, then progressively smaller.  Other things though you may not want to do as a habit but only for special occasions.

Comment: ewww, just looked at your first link, interview questions, dont read that, dont follow those suggestions, dont ask those questions to interview candidates.  Once you have a lot of experience in this area, then go back and look at that page.  yes there is some wisdom and experience there, but you have to know how and when to use it and not to use it.  It didnt go deep enough into the whys and hows and the dos and donts.